# Ball tracing mouse with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a simple game in AS3, similar to Tilt To Live.
I try to make a ball follow my mouse (an other ball) so when the ball touches the Mouseball you will lose. 
It's keep giving errors, and I dont really know how to solve it.

This is my game so far :

public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

```
    public function Main():void 
    {
    var vijand:Sprite = new Sprite ();
    vijand.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF66) ; 
    vijand.graphics.drawCircle(30,30 ,30 );
    addChild(vijand);

    var vijand1:Sprite = new Sprite ();
    vijand1.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF66) ; 
    vijand1.graphics.drawCircle(50,50 ,50 );
    addChild(vijand1);
    }

    public function beweeg(e:Event.):void
    {
    vijand.x = mouseX;
    vijand.y = mouseY;

    if (vijand.x > vijand1.x)
    {
        vijand1.x += 2;
    }


    if (vijand.y > vijand1.y)
    {
        vijand1.y += 2; 
    }



    if (vijand.x < vijand1.x)
    {
        vijand1.x -= 2; 
    }



    if (vijand.y < vijand1.y)
    {
            vijand1.y -= 2;
    }   

    }


    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is that your 'vijand' and 'vijand1' variables are local to your Main constructor. If you want to access them outside of the Main constructor function you will have to declare them outside of the constructor, eg:

```
private var vijand:Sprite = new Sprite();
private var vijand1:Sprite = new Sprite();

public function Main():void 
    {
    ....
```

Also there is a typo in the 'beweeg' function. Remove the '.' after 'Event':

```
public function beweeg(e:Event):void
{
....
```

Finally, you will also need an event listener to trigger the beweeg function. Probably an ENTER_FRAME listener in the Main constructor function:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, beweeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create correct logic for moving your objects. Here is example for you, actually it's funny, I have played some time before posting it

```
var myBall:Shape = new Shape();
var enemyBall:Shape = new Shape();
var ballRadius:int = 8;
var dx:Number, dy:Number, radian:Number, speed:Number = 10;

myBall.graphics.beginFill(0x009900);
myBall.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, ballRadius);

enemyBall.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
enemyBall.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, ballRadius);

addChild(myBall);
addChild(enemyBall);

//Place enemy at center
enemyBall.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
enemyBall.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    myBall.x = stage.mouseX;
    myBall.y = stage.mouseY;

    dx = myBall.x - enemyBall.x;
    dy = myBall.y - enemyBall.y;

    if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= ballRadius * 2) {
        //NOOOOOoooooo
        //Game over
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    } else {
        //Update enemy position
        //Every N ticks, increase speed, because it will be very easy game ;)
        radian = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        enemyBall.x += Math.cos(radian) * speed;
        enemyBall.y += Math.sin(radian) * speed;
    }
}
```